# Finding the components of the Riemannian tensor given the components of a metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am looking at a manifold of dimension $n$ (And I am considering a local co-ordinates system $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n$) and the metric defined by the components $g_{ij} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{x_1^2}$. I'm wanting to find the components of the corresponding Riemann tensor. This should be a pretty straight forward task but I cannot seem to match my workings to the actual answer.

Of course $g^{ij} = x_1^2\delta^{ij}$ and I have that $R^l_{ijk} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \Gamma^l_{ik} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} \Gamma^l_{ij} + \Gamma^s_{ik}\Gamma^l_{sj} - \Gamma^s_{ij}\Gamma^l_{sk}$

And I also have derived that $\Gamma^l_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}g^{lm}(g_{im,j}+g_{jk,i}-g_{ij,m})$

So I've done the hard stuff, and it should just be an easy calculation to get the the components of the Riemann tensor. But I can't get my answer to match.

Could someone please help me with the calculations please?

Many thanks!

Comment: What problem are you running into when do the calculations?

Comment: I don't actually know what I am doing incorrect. I presume I am making an error whilst indexing. But studying my work, I can't seem to fault it. That is when I thought it is best to see someone else's attempt.

Comment: And the reason I know I am making a mistake, and it's not just the notes that are incorrect, is because in this case the Weyl tensor is zero. And so if I were correct, my results would agree with that. Which they don't! Frustrating! If you could give you workings that would be very helpful thank you!

Comment: What answer are you getting?

Comment: It's probably easiest if I write what I got for the Ricci tensor, which was $ R_{ij} = \frac{1}{x_1^2}(2n \delta_{i,n+1} \delta_{j,n+1} - n\delta_{ij})$

Comment: Have you arrived at an answer?

Comment: I think you would get more help if you posted the calculation you have so far and let people identify potential errors rather than asking people to provide the whole calculation.

Comment: Dear @harrydunlop your new metric is a conformal change of the trivial metric $\delta _{ij}$. I think you can use any old article and just substitute.

Comment: Look at the calculation in P.160-162 in Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo. It is exactly what you needed except you have $g_{ij}=\frac{\delta_{ij}}{x_1^2}$, and they have $g_{ij}=\frac{\delta_{ij}}{x_n^2}$ in the book.